# Id does not appear to lower down in the same id. (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem when click in the first id=addfriends it show(work), but id below not work. The following of code.

Ok my wrong code. solved.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".addfriends").click(function(){
       var ajax_load = "<img src='http://localhost/anime/asset/img/loading.gif' alt='loading...' />"
       $('#result').html(ajax_load).load('http://localhost/anime/asset/html/add_friends.html #add-content-friends');
    });
    $(document).delegate(".close", 'click', function(){
        $("#add-content-friends").remove();    
    });
});

<div id="result"></div>

loop
    ...
    <tr><td><a id="addfriends" href="#add/<?php echo $comments['idusers']; ?>">Add friends</a></td></tr>
    ...
endloop

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("#addfriends", 'click', function(){
       var ajax_load = "<img src='...' alt='loading...' />"
       $('#result').html(ajax_load).load('../add_friends.html #add-content-friends');
    });
    $(document).on(".close", 'click', function(){
        $("#add-content-friends").remove();    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) not [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). So you need to change the order here:

```
$(document).on("click", '#addfriends', function(){
    var ajax_load = "<img src='...' alt='loading...' />"
    $('#result').html(ajax_load).load('../add_friends.html #add-content-friends');
});
```

and:

```
$(document).on("click", '.close', function(){
    $("#add-content-friends").remove();    
});
```

Currently , your order is: selector , events , handler.

The correct order here for on() is: events , selector , handler.

Also, `id` is unique, you need to use class instead for your anchors.

```
<a class="addfriends" href="#add/<?php echo $comments['idusers']; ?>">Add friends</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

[.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on("click", '#addfriends', function(){
```

---

Id must be Unique.

Read [Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

Use classes instead